# How to properly add elements to an array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two arrays as the code shows below (A and B). I would like to take as output `C = [[1, 2, 3, 11], [4, 5, 6, 12], [7, 8, 9, 13]]`

I'm trying to, but the only thing I could reach was this:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
B = [11, 12, 13]
C = [[x, y] for x, y in zip(A, B)]

print(C)
# Output: [[[1, 2, 3], 11], [[4, 5, 6], 12], [[7, 8, 9], 13]]
```

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Add element to a Python list", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: @Prune well, because of that search I've made, I came here to ask this.

Comment: Does it need to be a new list, or would modifying `A` also be ok?

Comment: _I have two arrays as the code shows below_ Those are lists, not arrays.

Comment: Please be more specific about what the issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make an array of a single element (`y`) and then add the two lists together

```
 [x + [y] for x, y in zip(A, B)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't need to be a new list and modifying `A` suffices:

```
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    a.append(b)
```

It's more efficient, at least for longer inner lists.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't have the same level of nesting in both A and B, which is why you got a weird answer. A is a list of lists, while B is just a list.

### Solutions

If you want to add inplace:

```
A.append(B)
# Output: A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Otherwise:

```
C = A + [B]
```

which leaves A and B untouched and creates a new joined list.

### Timings

Conclusion: for this problem it really doesn't matter which way you do it, as the timings are about the same for each case. Some ways are more readable though.

Code for timing:

```
import timeit

A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
B = [10, 11, 12]


def append_arrs(arrs=(A, B)):
    a, b = arrs
    a.append(b)
    return a


def plus_arrs(arrs=(A, B)):
    return arrs[0] + [arrs[1]]


def loopadd_arrs(arrs=(A, B)):
    return [x + [y] for x, y in zip(*arrs)]


def listadd_arrs(arrs=(A, B)):
    a, b = arrs
    return list((*a, b))


func_list = ["append_arrs", "plus_arrs", "loopadd_arrs", "listadd_arrs"]


for func in func_list:
    t = timeit.timeit(stmt=f'{func}', setup=f'from __main__ import {func}')
    print(f"Time for {func}: {t}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible with numpy

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
B = np.array([[11, 12, 13]]).T
C = np.append(A,B,axis=1)
```

Possibly you will have to transpose C according to the shape you want.